# Is there a simple way to generate a jstack for each running jvm?

Tags: java, bash, thread-dump

I would like to go like this

jstack ALL

or something like that so i can get the thread dump for all jvms on my system.

Can it be done?

Comment: You seem to be asking about the (unsupported) [`jstack`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jstack.html) command that I guess is packaged with some versions of Oracle's Java developer kit.  Thus, this isn't really a Java question *per se*, though of course it's Java-related.  I've added the [bash] tag, though if you're interested in doing this on Windows then a different one might be a more appropriate.

Comment: I don't need windows help but it might help someone else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [jstack command reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jstack.html) offers these three invocation forms:

> ```
> jstack [ options ] pid
>
> jstack [ options ] executable core
>
> jstack [ options ] [ server-id@ ] remote-hostname-or-IP
> ```

Of those, only the first is relevant to JVMs currently running on the same system where `jstack` runs.  Thus, you must identify the JVM processes by their pids.

In its summary of the `pid` argument, the reference notes:

> To get a list of Java processes running on a machine, use the jps(1) command.

Presumably, if you have `jstack` available to you then you also have `jps`.  The docs suggest that you might use `jps -q` to get a listing of only the relevant pids, that you therefore do not need to massage.  Given that, you could do something like this in `bash`:

```
for vmpid in $(jps -q); do
  jstack $vmpid
done
```

Evidently `jps` is implemented in Java, for I find that it reports on itself.  If that bothers you then the above could be tweaked to filter out `jps` itself.

Answer (score 1):

You could run the following in your terminal:

```
ps -e  | grep [j]ava  | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -n 1 jstack
```

Comment: `jps` might be a better choice as it will only give you the java processes you can connect to.